# Why $\sqrt{5}$ doesn't lie in $\mathbb{Q(\eta_{5})}$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

In *Lorenz's Galois Theory* book, there's a problem :

> Why $\sqrt{15} \notin \mathbb{Q(\eta_{15})}$, where $\eta_{15}$ is a
>   $15$-th primitive root of unity ?

But My question is about what it's written in the hint :

> Why $\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q(\eta_{5})}$ ?

Now, I see that $G(\mathbb{Q(\eta_{15})}/Q)\simeq U_{15}\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2^2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and hence has $7$ subgroups: $\{(0,0)\}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{2^2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, etc.

There's written in that problem that the corresponding subfields of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\eta_{15})/\mathbb{Q}$ are : $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\eta_5)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\eta_5+{\eta_5}^{-1})$: It's not hard that these subfields are distinct and hence they're only subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\eta_{15})/\mathbb{Q}$.

Here is the hint : "$\sqrt{-3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\eta_3)$ and $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}(\eta_5)$", but I can't understand why $\sqrt5$ lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\eta_5)$ and by this assumption, I've no idea how to continue right now.

Comment: You're already done; in particular, you've already listed the quadratic subfields, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$ wasn't one of them.

Comment: Oh yes i'm now done ... 
I'm really getting mad

Comment: But still I can't understand why $\sqrt5 \in \mathbb{Q}(\eta_5)$ :(

Comment: Fardad, we always have $\sqrt{p^*}\in\Bbb{Q}(\eta_p)$ for all (odd) primes $p$. here $p^*=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$. Read about [Gauss sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) for one explanation.

Comment: It's the same argument as the other one: you can compute all of the quadratic subfields, and the only one will turn out to be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$.